# ag-grid with NVDA screen reader accessibility

Tags: accessibility, ag-grid, screen-readers, nvda

I am using ag-grid with screen readers. To be identified as table, added display properties (display:table, display:table-row', etc). Table is identified(shift T), but table shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrow keys work only with Chrome+JAWS, but not with Chrome+NVDA.
Did anyone get into this issue? What needs to be done to make table shortcut keys work with Chrome+NVDA?

Comment: What does the generated html look like?  Is it using native `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` elements?  Or is it trying to fake a table using `<div>` and other non-semantic elements?  The latter would require various table roles, https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#table

Comment: CSS display properties for table, row, cell etc. are not exposed in the browser's accessibility tree, so screen readers should not recognise them. Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Please give us an idea of what the markup looks like. This has a huge impact on screen reader behaviour.